# Deserialize Blockchain.info JSON

Tags: json, vb.net, blockchain

I'm using Blockchain.info API. I want to deserialize the JSON response. An example response:

```
{
    "addresses": [
        {
            "balance": 1400938800,
            "address": "1Q1AtvCyKhtveGm3187mgNRh5YcukUWjQC",
            "label": "SMS Deposits",
            "total_received": 5954572400
        },
        {
            "balance": 79434360,
            "address": "1A8JiWcwvpY7tAopUkSnGuEYHmzGYfZPiq",
            "label": "My Wallet",
            "total_received": 453300048335
        },
        {
            "balance": 0,
            "address": "17p49XUC2fw4Fn53WjZqYAm4APKqhNPEkY",
            "total_received": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is how to make a class that fits this.
I tried this but it's not working:

```
Public Function LoadJson(ByVal json As String)
    Dim items As List(Of addresses) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of addresses))(json)
    Return items
End Function
Public Class addresses
    Public addresses As address()
End Class
Public Class address
    Public balance
    Public address
    Public label
    Public total_received
End Class
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try Dim items As List(Of address) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of address))(json)

Comment: No, it's not working.

Comment: You get errors? can you step through your code and give us a bit more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may figure out in a simple manner :

go there http://json2csharp.com/ paste your json and it will make your class and its dependency.

then you may create your new one in your app and the use simply javascript.serialize,deserialize nothing else and it will work perfectly

here below a fully work console application example working perfectly:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Module Module1
    Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer

    Sub Main()

    Dim json As String = String.Empty

    Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\Users\Giorgio\Desktop\GOOGLEDRIVE\hpc\PROGETTI VS PERSONALI\VISUALSTUDIOPROJECT\2014\Smples\Smples\json.txt")
        json = sr.ReadToEnd
    End Using
    Dim separator As String = "**********************************************************"
    Dim root As RootObject = js.Deserialize(Of RootObject)(json)

    For Each el In root.addresses
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}" & vbCrLf & "{1}" & vbCrLf & "{2}" & vbCrLf & "{3}" & vbCrLf & separator, el.address, el.balance, el.label, el.total_received))
    Next


        Console.ReadLine()
End Sub


Public Class Address
    Public Property balance() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_balance
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_balance = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_balance As Integer
    Public Property address() As String
        Get
            Return m_address
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_address = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_address As String
    Public Property label() As String
        Get
            Return m_label
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_label = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_label As String
    Public Property total_received() As Object
        Get
            Return m_total_received
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_total_received = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_total_received As Object
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property addresses() As List(Of Address)
        Get
            Return m_addresses
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Address))
            m_addresses = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_addresses As List(Of Address)
End Class
```

End Module

I hope it can help you
Regards